# How can I convert Selenese to Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Python 3 was released in 2008. Around the time Selenium IDE was developed. It's crazy that the IDE still doesn't support exporting to Python 3 after 9 years!

How can I export the recorded Selenese to a Python 3 format?